# Elastic Search- Searching Multiple Queries in Single Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I'm new to elastic Search. I have a field name `clearance` in my `users` table and I'm trying to filter my results based on this.

```
match: {
          clearance: {
            query: 'None',
            type: 'phrase'
          }
        }
```

When I give the above match query i get 3 results. What I'm trying to get is to pass one more string along with `None`. For eg I want to find the users with clearance `None` and `First Level`

I tried this.

```
multi_match: {
              clearance: {
                query: 'None OR First Level',
                type: 'phrase'
              }
            }
```

But ended up in some error. Please Help. Correct me if my question is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be making clearance as not_analyzed field in the mapping and using terms filter.

Example:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "e1":{
      "properties": {
        "clearance":{
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some test data:

```
PUT test/e1/1
{
  "clearance":"None"
}
PUT test/e1/2
{
  "clearance":"First Level"
}
PUT test/e1/3
{
  "clearance":"Second Level"
}
```

Now query part:

```
GET test/e1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "clearance": [
            "None",
            "First Level"
          ],
          "execution": "or"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result verfication:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "e1",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "clearance": "None"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "e1",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "clearance": "First Level"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```